# Multiprocessing: Load data and run computation

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to do some computations on huge numpy arrays as fast as possible.
In order to do that I tried `threading` but it wasn't using all available CPUs. So I'm trying with `multiprocessing` but as the memory is not shared between process I'd like to know if it's possible to:

- Load data in a process (worker) and keep it in memory
- Do some computation on this data each time I call a function of these workers

I've tried the following code:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        self.matrix = pd.read_csv(self.csv_path).as_matrix()

    def matrix_count_worker(rule):
        return np.nansum(self.matrix[eval(rule), :], axis=0)
```

But then I would like to start my processes and **keep them active**. So something like a `.start()` first. But then I'd like be able to call `matrix_count_worker` as many times as I want, while `self.matrix` stays loaded in memory.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: will worker modify self.matrix?

Comment: Sharing memory is difficult, but not impossible, using `multiprocessing`, and incurs a lot of overhead (it's expensive processing-wise). If the processes don't modify the matrix, it could very well be better to have each one read it into its own memory space when it starts.

Comment: Nope, the worker on do some sums/filter on the matrix but doesn't alter it. However, I need to sum the results of each `matrix_count_worker`!

Comment: `multiprocessing` is a way around the GIL. The GIL doesn't really apply to numpy code or pandas. I'm not sure you get any benefit from using multiprocessing here.

Comment: I've done some benchmarks, with 5 threads it's 5 time faster. However when I try with 30 threads, I see that all my CPU aren't fully used. That's why I want to try with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Being read-only makes things easier. Another alternative would be to pass the matrix as an argument. Since the results sounds small and simple it can be passed back a the process' return value. You also don't need to derive a subclass of `Process`. Just write a standalone function as pass it to the `Process` constructor with a `target=<funcion name>` keyword argument in the calling sequence.

Comment: If you're doing CPU-bound work, adding more threads than cores won't help, and will start to hurt at some point.

Comment: @martineau The ouput value of matrix_count_worker is pretty small, yes. However `matrix`is different for every worker, and pretty big. So if I don't derive a subclass of `Process`, how can I bind this matrix to a specific worker?

Comment: @bnaecker I've 40 CPU available here, so I'm always having less threads than available CPUs.

Comment: I do not know if it will help, but there are good comparisons here: https://github.com/JohnStarich/python-pool-performance

Comment: Robin: "`self.matrix `stays loaded in memory" sounds like it's the same matrix for each "worker". Anyway, as I said, you can pass it as an argument to the `matrix_count_worker()` (or whatever it's named) target function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need to accelerate calculation on a huge array?

Take a look at [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), it works best with huge arrays and can use all of your cores.